# AdMob up carret loading

Tags: android, admob

I implemented AdMob  in my app on main activity. In `onCreate` method I got:

```
 mAdView = (AdView) this.findViewById(R.id.adView);
            AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
            mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);
```

On `onResume`, I got:

```
    super.onResume();
    if (mAdView!= null) {
        mAdView.resume();            
    }
```

I got similar code on `onDestroy` and `onPause` methods(in `onPause` I call `mAdView.pause()` etc. ).
Here is my `adView` in `activity_main.xml`:

```
<com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        ads:adSize="BANNER"
        ads:adUnitId="ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|bottom"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
         />
```

When I leave the main activity and press back button to get back to that activity, the add is shown immediately, but if I press the up caret < in the action bar, it takes some time to reload the add and show it on the screen.
Is there a way to show adds on main activity immediately after pressing up caret on second activity, like modifying `onPause` and other methods on these activities to not destroy that AdMob object? 
Should I implement the adds in some other way to maximize adds showing time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just added android:launchMode="singleTop" in my apps manifest file in the main activities tag. This line makes parent activity to be brought to the top of the stack, and its state is preserved. 
More details on: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#lmode